# ArcMap's "Join Field" tool takes so long when just "Joining" works instantly. Help?

Tags: arcmap

I'm using ArcMap and I'm trying to write a script that automates a join and then does some reporting.

I'm not very experienced with joins and I'm running into a problem.
When I do a join manually (right clicking the shapefile and specifying the join) it does the join seemingly automatically. 
However, when I try and do a "Join Field" in ModelBuilder it takes a really long time. Minutes.

Is there a different method of automating a join using python or Model Builder that runs faster?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the tool help you'll note that [Join Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Join_Field/001700000065000000/) permanently adds 1 or more fields to the input table.

The tool you probably want is [Add Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/0017/001700000064000000.htm), which works more like the interactive join command to create a temporary join.

You'll probably want to use [Remove Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Remove_Join/001700000066000000/) when you're done though to clean up after yourself.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to blah238's answer, you should also use the [Add Attribute Index](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005z000000) geoprocessing tool to create an index for the join. This tool accomplishes the same thing as this prompt:

[image]

This will greatly increase performance. Note that some read-only table file types (e.g. CSV) don't support attribute indices, so you'll have to export them to a .dbf file first.

Comment: creating an index for the join field in the join table sounds a good idea, but would it also be advised to create an index on the join field of the target layer? @dmahr

Answer (score 2):

This has been reported to the ArcGIS Ideas forum here: https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/8679

A python script to automate joining the fast way has been provided here:
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=da1540fb59d84b7cb02627856f65a98d

Comment: should be noted this script only works with GDB inputs

Comment: I struggled with awesome slow JoinField in my script. The link to the python script is worth a lot. Following the instructions there I reduced overall calculation time to 1/7.